# Translation of "profit formula"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In [this article by Mark Johnson](https://hbr.org/2008/12/reinventing-your-business-model/ar/1), the term *profit formula* is used. He describes it like so:

> The profit formula is the blueprint that defines how the company creates value for itself while providing value to the customer.

I could only come up with "Gewinnschema" / "Gewinnformel", but don't really think this is a good translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries say:

formula: Formel/Rezept
profit: Nutzen/Gewinn/Profit

But a *Profitformel* sounds odd. Thinking of a company this makes me use the word "plan" or "model" - like a 'Finanzplan'.

So I think **Profitmodell** or even more **Erfolgsmodell** sounds good to me.

Comment: I really like "Profitmodell", thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Vielleicht "das Geheimnis des Erfolges"? Oder Erfolgsrezept? Auch wenn beides nicht wörtlich ist.

Comment: Diese Übersetzungen wären leider wirklich schon zu weit weg vom Ursprung, denke ich. Trotzdem danke!